# Insert a Dynamic into Elastic Document through nest

Tags: elasticsearch, dynamic, nest

```
var doc = new ESDoc {
   Field1 = "test1",
   Field2 = 3,
   ExtraData = 'dynamic object',
   Index = "myindex"
};

ElasticClient.Index(doc, s => s.Index(doc.Index));
```

This is in essence what I am trying to do. I have a document object, and I am wanting to add to it a dynamic object that allows us to through whatever customer specific data we want in there. I have no need to ever search or do any querying on it, I just need to hold it for CYA issues.

This results in ExtraData having a value_kind = 1.

I tried to JsonSerializer.Serialize the data and it came out in a triple escaped string.

I have seen people trying to create a entire document of dynamic data, and using a object cast, but I feel that isnt the answer here because I have a document that I want to add a dynamic object too.

NEST and Elaticsearch.Net 7.16.0

Comment: Have you tried [index=false](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) ? It might work with `type=object` or `type=flattened` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following:

1. You need to have a type to model the *dynamic* behaviour of the field. Now, you could specify it as `dynamic` on the `ESDoc` class, but you'll need an instance of a type to assign to it and Nest deserializes JSON to a `Dictionary<string, object>` for a `dynamic` member. Because of this, you might want to use the `DynamicDictionary` type in Elasticsearch.Net (a dependency of Nest) that is a dictionary with dynamic access behaviour

   ```cs
   public class ESDoc
   {
       public string Field1 { get; set; }

       public int Field2 { get; set; }

       public DynamicDictionary ExtraData { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Map `ExtraData` as [`object` data type with `enabled: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), so that it is not parsed and indexed

   ```cs
   var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create("myindex", c => c
       .Map<ESDoc>(m => m
           .Properties(p => p
               .Text(t => t
                   .Name(f => f.Field1)
               )
               .Number(t => t
                   .Name(f => f.Field2)
                   .Type(NumberType.Integer)
               )
               .Object<object>(o => o
                   .Name(f => f.ExtraData)
                   .Enabled(false)
               )
           )
       )
   );
   ```
3. Now index a doc, refresh the index, and search for it to ensure it deserializes as expected

   ```cs
   dynamic extraData = new DynamicDictionary();
   extraData.foo = "Foo";
   extraData.bar = new DynamicDictionary
   {
       ["baz"] = new DynamicValue("Baz")
   };

   var doc = new ESDoc
   {
       Field1 = "test1",
       Field2 = 3,
       ExtraData = extraData
   };

   client.Index(doc, s => s.Index("myindex")); 
   client.Indices.Refresh("myindex");   
   var searchResponse = client.Search<ESDoc>(s => s.Index("myindex"));

   var firstDoc = searchResponse.Documents.First();
   var baz = firstDoc.ExtraData["bar"]["baz"];

   Console.WriteLine($"{baz}");
   ```